# Does Ubuntu Phone support RTC Alarm?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, acpi

Is `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` present? Does phone wake up after setting it when it's completely switched off? What does it do when the phone is locked?

Will it be supported in hardware by all phones/SOCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not part of Canonical, so I can't say what the plan is, but currently, mako, flo and hammerhead don't support rtc alarm (plus, hammerhead's RTC is kinda broken/rendered broken by other broken things). There are however some fixes in CyanogenMod's kernel for mako and flo which seem to fix it[1], so it is probably possible to make it work.

[1] for example this commit: https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_kernel_google_msm/commit/c1429d6f7a8dc54f222aea14d63974cfca3d8df8